# Accidentally deleted /bin on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

I deleted `/bin` folder on Ubuntu 16.04 by mistake. There was a folder named `bin` in home folder and I deleted `/bin` folder instead `~/bin` folder in home folder. Unfortunately, when I restarted my PC, it didn't boot.

I have important files in home folder and the home folder it is not in separate partition from OS.
Is upgrading the system to a newer version via bootable USB flash useful to solve this problem?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: As to your upgrade solution question; you specify Ubuntu 16 at one point but tagged 16.04 (different products), and didn't say if Desktop or Server; but assuming 16.04 Desktop; yes an *upgrade via re-install* would fix the issue.  If you use *Something else*, select existing partition(s) but do **not** format, no user file is touched. System directories are wiped (thus it'll fix your issue) before re-install, even additional packages get re-installed (if available in Ubuntu repos) assuming you don't format!

Comment: Sorry os is ubuntu 16 desktop so If upgrading the system didn't solve the problem, would the second solution u assumed help me?

Comment: Ubuntu products that use the *year* format are designed for *headless* operation, servers usually on devices/appliances or in the cloud; eg. Ubuntu Core 16.  Ubuntu desktop releases are all *deb* based and use the *year.month* format unlike *year* products which are *snap* only.

Comment: Yep.  it's what I'd do , *upgrade via re-install* using *Something else*, re-use the partitions but do **NOT** format as that is the trigger for the install method I'm suggesting.  It doesn't matter than /home shares the same partition - key is you do **NOT** use any install that uses format (that will erase your data!)  You should backup first from a *live* system.

Comment: Ok thank u very much

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu Desktop releases (inc. *flavors*), you can *Upgrade via re-install*.

Boot the *live* system

Start the `ubiquity` installer for Ubuntu Desktop and using *Something else* (*Manual Partitioning* with `calamares`)

- Select your existing partition(s)
- ensure you don't have FORMAT tagged

It will cause the following to occur

- your installed packages are noted
- your system directories are erased (desktop apps don't store data in system directories; some server apps do though)
- new system is installed
- any additional packages you had installed (noted earlier) get re-installed IF available in your new release from Ubuntu repositories
- no user file is touched (unless you selected format)
- you are asked to reboot

It's far faster than a *release-upgrade*, and my usual fall back for an install that went wrong (and I'm too lazy to fix it), or I don't have time to *release-upgrade*.

Complications can occur if you have an encrypted system, as Ubuntu 17.10 & earlier used different encryption to 18.04 & later, so the package some encrypted installs need is no longer included by default; but that can be worked around via a manual install during the *live* session prior to starting the installed (`ubiquity`).

*Of course, and as always you should always have backups as things can happen (power goes out etc) so backup your data first using the *live* session prior to install.*

Comment: To me the question (*as currently written*) is still off-topic; as it's about an EOL/ESM release.  If however the question was written (it currently mentions it in minor detail) to be about re-install fix; then this answer is on-topic...

Comment: Also FYI for anyone using this type of *upgrade via re-install*.  It's common for you to get an error message at the end of the install that packages could not be re-installed; this is not unexpected; eg. if going from 18.04 to 20.04 both Qt4 & python2 were removed from repositories due EOL so packages that required those weren't available in *focal*... 16.04 -> 18.04 was too long ago for me to now recall what occurred between *xenial* & *bionic* cycles; but packages are likely to have been removed; let alone 3rd party packages are more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following way to recover your current Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version without reinstall:

1. You boot the original installation Ubuntu 16.04 LTS LiveCD/LiveUSD in Try Ubuntu mode, then mount your current operating system partition and copy `/bin` folder from LiveCD/LiveUSB to the OS partition by using command like `sudo cp -ar /bin /media/ubuntu/OS/` or with GUI, then reboot;
2. After first successful login to your OS, you can reinstall the packages which have files in `/bin` by using command below:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /bin | sed "s/,//g" | sed "s|: /bin||")
   ```
3. To keep system consistent locate extra executable files which were copied from LiveCD/LiveUSB, but should not exist in your OS, and remove them manually by using command below

   ```
   find /bin -type f -exec dpkg -S {} \; 2> ~/not-from-apt.out
   ```

   then carefully inspect the contents of `~/not-from-apt.out` and remove binary files which are listed here. Or use one-liner below if you are sure:

   ```
   sudo rm -v -i $(cat ~/not-from-apt.out | awk '{print $7}')
   ```
4. Then upgrade this system to newer 18.04 LTS release by `sudo do-release-upgrade` or by using `update-manager -c`.